# sql query on dual

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

This:

```
    select * 
      from dual  
connect by level <= i
```

...will return result  as

```
1
2
3
...
i
```

Can the query be modified to get result row wise? i.e

```
1 2 3 .....i
```

Answer (score 4):

The functionality you're after is called "pivot"--it's converting row data into columnar data.  The opposite is called "unpivot".  There is PIVOT/UNPIVOT syntax, but it isn't available until Oracle 11g.

On Oracle 9i+, [CASE statements](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/case.php) are used while prior to that you need to use [DECODE](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/decode.php) to construct the logic so the values come out in columns.  Here's an example for addressing if the limit to LEVEL is five on Oracle 9i+:

```
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 1 THEN LEVEL END) AS one,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 2 THEN LEVEL END) AS two,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 3 THEN LEVEL END) AS three,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 4 THEN LEVEL END) AS four,
           MAX(CASE WHEN LEVEL = 5 THEN LEVEL END) AS five
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5
```

The aggregate function MAX is necessary to "flatten" the resultset into a single row/record.

If you got this far, you're thinking "but I don't want to have to specify for every column--I want it to be dynamic based on *i*...".  There's two issues:

1. There is a limit to the number of columns - see [ORA-01792 maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000](http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96525/e1500.htm#1001271).  That goes for 8i & 9i, anyways.  And frankly, needing to generate that many columns raises serious questions about what you're trying to do with the resultset, if there might be a better approach...
2. [Dynamic requirements means using dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm)

Comment: Yes, Your guess is absolutely correct. I want to select columns dynamically.Thanks

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this answer, I just wanted to add that the query is functionally equivalent to `select 1,2,3,4,5 from dual`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select trim(both ',' from sys_connect_by_path(level, ',')) as string
  from dual
 where level = 100
connect by level <= 100
```

**update:** Testing the output:

```
SQL> 
SQL>  select trim(both ',' from sys_connect_by_path(level, ',')) as string
  2     from dual
  3    where level = 20
  4   connect by level <= 20
  5  /

STRING
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20
```

**another update:** Guess I haven't read all comments well enough before posting, sorry. :) If you need to select each number as a separate column, then yes, see, OMG Ponies' answer - it's either pivot or dynamic SQL. :)